# How to tell two certificate pairs are issued by different CA in Golang?

Tags: go

I have a GOlang http server which uses self-signed tls certificate. I have one such pair of certificate and key. Now, say I have a similar certificate and key pair. I would like to detect whether these two pairs were issued by two different CA? I don't have access to the CA certificates in this case. I can assume that the chain length = 1.

I tried to check the Certificate.Issuer structure. But I see no difference there. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Selfsigned certs you created are **not issued by _any_ CA**. A selfsigned cert's issuer is the same as the subject; that's what selfsigned means. If you created the certs with different values in subject&issuer the different values are different and you can tell them apart; if you created the certs with the same value the same value is the same and two same values are not different.

Answer (score 1):

The [`SubjectKeyId` fields](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#Certificate) will be different for two distinct certificates.

This field is a hash of the public key:

> The keyIdentifier is composed of the 160-bit SHA-1 hash of the
> value of the BIT STRING subjectPublicKey (excluding the tag,
> length, and number of unused bits).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.2.1.2

For certificates that are not self-signed one would follow the `AuthorityKeyId` fields all the way to the root certificate(s) and then check the certificate chains for common members, again using the subject keys.